# Getting different results when seemingly trying to get the same range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a problem which could also be a bug, either way, I don't know how to resolve it and would appreciate any help :)

```
i2 = 2
plz1 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i2)
plz2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & i2)
```

B2 is 89999 and C2 is 90000. So when running this code plz1 is 89999 and plz 2 is "90000" (notice the quotation marks).

So:

```
plz1 = 89999
plz2 = "90000"
```

This is quite an issue since I want to create a range:

```
Range(plz1 & ":" & plz2)
```

I don't know if I am just doing a really obvious stupid mistake or if it's a bug...

I would really appreciate any advice I can get! :))

Thanks, NiceRice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you mean to construct a range of numbers or a range of rows.

Here is how you can deal with either a text 90000 or "90000" in a cell. Also, then have a testNumber and see if it is between plz1 and plz2.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

Dim i2 As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'Change as appropriate

Dim plz1 As Long
Dim plz2 As Long

i2 = 2

'Get rid of any "" if present in string

If InStr(1, ws.Range("C" & i2), Chr(34)) > 0 Then
    ws.Range("C" & i2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(ws.Range("C" & i2), Chr(34), "")
End If

On Error GoTo NotConverted

plz1 = CLng(ws.Range("B" & i2))
plz2 = CLng(ws.Range("C" & i2))

Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = ws.Range(plz1 & ":" & plz2)

MsgBox myRange.Address

Dim testNumber As Long
testNumber = 1238

If testNumber >= plz1 And testNumber <= plz2 Then
    MsgBox "testNumber is between " & plz1 & " and " & plz2
End If

Exit Sub

NotConverted:
MsgBox "The contents of either cell B" & i2 & " or C" & i2 & " could not be converted to a number."

End Sub
```

Comment: Omg... Thanks so much for your answer! Such a sleek way of solving it with =<... How could I forget to do it like that... Thanks so much!

Comment: If I could ask one more quick question, why do you choose to define the variables as long instead of integer? Thanks!

Comment: There aren't really any memory saving on modern computers with using Integer over Long. Long can store a longer number so less risk of overflow. It's safer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this instead?

```
Sub Combined_range()
i2 = 2
Sheets("Sheet2").Range ("B" & i2 & ":C" & i2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I tried it and it didn't work. I think that is due to the range not refering to the cell contents any more. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hello. What are you trying to select? In this example, would it be rows 89999:90000?

Comment: No, sorry my description wasn't clear. I want to check if a number is included in the range 89999:90000 e.g. 90000 is included, and 1238 isn't